# CheckBox + калькулятор

Tags: checkbox, html, javascript

Доброго времени суток.

Есть калькулятор, который суммирует чекбоксы. Код можно [посмотреть тут](http://jsfiddle.net/alegraft/x65djjj8/4/).

**Задача:** Есть два блока. Надо в каждом из них чекбоксы объединить в группу и дать им одну цену. Грубо говоря, блок - это пакет услуг. Человек в этом блоке выбирает 1,2 или 3 пункта (чекбокса), но платит все равно одну сумму. То же самое и со вторым блоком. А потом уже эти блоки суммируются. Но есть уточнение, что будут блоки-пакеты и отдельные чекбоксы со своей ценой, как в рабочем примере. Примерный код [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/alegraft/q24z7zym/2/).

Но ума не приложу, как это реализовать.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Небольшой совет: такие объемные тексты лучше размещать в другом месте.

В данном случае отлично подойдет [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Там можно будет не только показать код, но и сразу посмотреть как он работает.

Т.е. там можно сделать два проекта (без регистрации): первый - с тем, что есть сейчас, второй - с тем, что должно быть (примерно).

Либо, как вариант, делаете скришот того, что есть, делаете рисунок того, что должно, и выкладываете сюда. Того, что есть сейчас, - дополнительно выложить на jsFiddle.

**Обновление**

Вот так уже лучше ) Сразу понятно, что вы хотите. Вас чистый JS интересует? Или пример на jQuery можно привести?

Только небольшое уточнение: если я в первом блоке выбрал первый чекбокс, затем второй, то сумма не изменится? Ведь я ее уже изменил при нажатии на первый чекбокс. При этом если выбрать из второй группы элемент, то сумма изменится. Все верно?

**Обновление**

Посмотрите, в таком виде вас устроит решение: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q24z7zym/3/). Решение еще пилить и пилить надо, но для начала, думаю пойдет )

Comment: Совершенно верно. Грубо говоря, блок - это пакет услуг. Человек в этом блоке выбирает 1,2 или 3 пункта (чекбокса), но платит все равно одну сумму. То же самое и со вторым блоком. А потом уже эти блоки суммируются.

Но есть уточнение, что будут блоки-пакеты и отдельные чекбоксы со своей ценой, как в рабочем примере.

JS или jQuery - это не принципиально. Я стараюсь учить оба, но второй почему-то кажется легче.

Comment: Благодарю, все работает отлично. Тоже подумывал в сторону onckick, но с JS на вы, вот и не смог объединить калькулятор и чекбоксы.
        
Вопрос: а почему вы не написали ответ в "Ответ"?

Answer (score 1):

[@alegraft](/users/26112/alegraft), я так понимаю, что это у вас продолжается эпопея с чекбоксами )) И почему вы упорно ползёте к убогому коду? Обработчик событий внутри тегов - это не есть гуд! Если что-то нужно хранить в тегах элементов, то лучше это делать с помощью атрибута **data-***. Если взять код из предыдущего вашего вопроса, то [доработать его можно так](http://jsfiddle.net/0yrLaaL8/3/).

```
<div class="block">
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="main">00</p>
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="100">01
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="150">02
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="180">03
</div>
<div class="block">
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="main">00</p>
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="250">01
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="55">02
    <input type="checkbox" data-price="75">03
</div>
<output></output>
```

JS

```
var allChbx = [],
    out = document.querySelector('output');
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.block'), function(group){
    var main = group.querySelector('.main'),
        chbx = group.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not(.main)');
    allChbx = allChbx.concat([].slice.call(chbx));
    main.addEventListener('change', function(){
        var stat = this.checked;
        [].forEach.call(chbx, function(el){
            el.checked = stat;
        });
        reCalc();
    });
    [].forEach.call(chbx, function(el){
        el.addEventListener('change',function(){
            var cnt = [].filter.call(chbx, function(el){
                return el.checked == true;
            }).length;
            main.checked = cnt > 0;
            reCalc();
        }, false);
    });
});
function reCalc(){
    var total = 0;
    allChbx.forEach(function(c){
        total += c.checked == true ? +c.dataset.price : 0;
    });
    out.innerHTML = 'Итого: <b>' + total + '</b> тугриков';
}
```

Самому же будет приятней работать, когда "мухи отдельно, а котлеты отдельно". Пусть JS будет в своём файле и не нужно его смешивать с HTML. Это же касается и CSS

Comment: Насчет мух и котлет я не спорю, с html и css так и делаю. С JS пока только с учебником кое-как. И когда он в теге, то чисто визуально проще разобраться, что, как и зачем работает. В дальнейшем, естественно, буду расти в этом плане. И благодарю за ваш вариант.