# CheckBox + JavaScript + калькулятор

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть решения по калькуляторам с Чекбоксами [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/382291/checkbox-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)
Но работает только если одно вложение.
Надо вот к этому коду:

```html
<aside>
  <section>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><label><input type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>1</span></label></li>
        <li><label><input title="1" type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>2</span></label></li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><label><input title="1" type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>2/1</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input title="1" type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>2/2</span></label></li>
            <li><label><input title="1" type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>2/3</span></label>
              <ul>
                <li><label><input title="1" type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>2/3/1</span></label></li>
                <li><label><input title="1" type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>2/3/2</span></label></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><label><input title="1" type="checkbox" data-price="100"><span>3</span></label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Пробовал натянуть на [вот этот скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/0yrLaaL8/3/), но естественно не смог.

Нужна помощь, рассмотрю все варианты.

Comment: По какой-то причине тот вопрос решат удалить ... jsFiddle может не работать .... ну вы понимаете о чем я ... вставьте пожалуйста в тело вопроса все: и какое решение пробовали, и что вам в этом всем не приглянулось, что бы этот вопрос мог быть полезен даже ввиду различных катаклизмов.

Comment: @MedvedevDev , вот набросал что нужно мне в итоге http://z93251c6.beget.tech/ , суть в том, что нужно, чтоб работало в каждой, новой ветке "меню". Сейчас у меня только у первых потомков работает, а нужно, чтоб хотб до вторых.